# [CARTOGRAPHER-ROS] "Submaps: For frame [map]: Frame [map] does not exist"

Tags: ros, rviz, cartographer, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey, I have tried for a while now to get my Lidar setup to work with Cartographer ROS, with mixed results. I am using 2D lidar exclusively (Hokuyo ust-10lx, no imu).

My current launch files:

```
<launch>
  <param name="/use_sim_time" value="true" />

  <include file="$(find cartographer_ros)/launch/backpack_2d.launch" />

  <node name="rviz" pkg="rviz" type="rviz" required="true"
      args="-d $(find cartographer_ros)/configuration_files/demo_2d.rviz" />
  <node name="playbag" pkg="rosbag" type="play"
      args="--clock $(arg bag_filename)" />
    <param name="frame_id" value="/base_link"/>
</launch>
<launch>
  <param name="robot_description"
    textfile="$(find cartographer_ros)/urdf/backpack_2d.urdf" />

  <node name="robot_state_publisher" pkg="robot_state_publisher"
    type="robot_state_publisher" />

  <node name="cartographer_node" pkg="cartographer_ros"
      type="cartographer_node" args="
          -configuration_directory $(find cartographer_ros)/configuration_files
          -configuration_basename my_robot.lua"
      output="screen">
    <remap from="echoes" to="horizontal_laser_2d" />
  </node>

  <node name="cartographer_occupancy_grid_node" pkg="cartographer_ros"
      type="cartographer_occupancy_grid_node" args="-resolution 0.05" />
</launch>
```

and my current lua file:

```
options = {
      map_builder = MAP_BUILDER,
      trajectory_builder = TRAJECTORY_BUILDER,
      map_frame = "map",
      tracking_frame = "base_link",
      published_frame = "base_link",
      odom_frame = "odom",
      provide_odom_frame = true,
      publish_frame_projected_to_2d = false,
      use_odometry = false,
      use_nav_sat = false,
      use_landmarks = false,
      num_laser_scans = 1,
      num_multi_echo_laser_scans = 0,
      num_subdivisions_per_laser_scan = 1, --10
      num_point_clouds = 0,
      lookup_transform_timeout_sec = 0.2,
      submap_publish_period_sec = 0.3,
      pose_publish_period_sec = 5e-3,
      trajectory_publish_period_sec = 30e-3,
      rangefinder_sampling_ratio = 1.,
      odometry_sampling_ratio = 1.,
      fixed_frame_pose_sampling_ratio = 1.,
      imu_sampling_ratio = 1.,
      landmarks_sampling_ratio = 1.,
    }
    
    MAP_BUILDER.use_trajectory_builder_2d = true
    TRAJECTORY_BUILDER_2D.num_accumulated_range_data = 1081
    TRAJECTORY_BUILDER_2D.use_imu_data = false;
```

The rosbag that I am using is (only contains topic laserScan /scan (fixed_frame = base_link):
1: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AlYv1byT4VoNgySe8gF8ibUl_kam
This one gives no visual results at all
2: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AlYv1byT4VoNgyUujvs13GrZW0a5
This one gives the result shown below
The only difference between the two bags is that the Lidar moves in the first one but remains at the same position in the second one.

When run, cartographer does not give any errors in the terminal, but both submaps and constraints are missing frame map.
Pictures of result, rqt_graph and rqt_tf_tree:
[image]
[image]
[image]

If I change the fixed frame name from base_link to map, both the RobotModel and the global status give errors as they require base_link to be present.

My question:
What am I missing in my tf connections/cartographer settings?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/352150/%5Bcartographer-ros%5D-%22submaps:-for-frame-%5Bmap%5D:-frame-%5Bmap%5D-does-not-exist%22/) by [D.Schalk](https://answers.ros.org/users/54853/d.schalk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2020-05-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Do you have `return options` at the end of your lua file?

Edit:
This seems too high. `TRAJECTORY_BUILDER_2D.num_accumulated_range_data = 1081`
Set it to e.g. `TRAJECTORY_BUILDER_2D.num_accumulated_range_data = 1` and it worked for me in Gazebo. I believe this is the number of messages you want to accumulate for a full "revolution" of the scanner.

---

Originally posted by [bob-ROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/45543/bob-ros/) with karma: 525 on 2020-05-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [D.Schalk](https://answers.ros.org/users/54853/d.schalk/) on 2020-05-13**:
Yes I have

**Comment by [D.Schalk](https://answers.ros.org/users/54853/d.schalk/) on 2020-05-29**:
I still have not found an answer

**Comment by [bob-ROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/45543/bob-ros/) on 2020-05-30**:
Updating my answer

**Comment by [D.Schalk](https://answers.ros.org/users/54853/d.schalk/) on 2020-06-01**:
That was indeed the problem! Both rosbags with scan data from a stationary and moving car create a map. Thank you very much